# getPurchaseUpdates doesn't return anything when using Amazon App Tester

Tags: in-app-purchase, amazon-fire-tv

I am trying testing purchase using amazon app tester.

I need to handle purchase updates, but I receive empty list of receipts.

I've red this https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-design-test-cases.html#purchase-updates-request
Here is my amazon app tester settings:

[API Resposnse Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgeOF.png)

get not empty response from App Tester (getPurchaseUpdates)

Comment: ​I have solved this problem by downgrading amazon library to 2.0.76